# How do I call a component using javascript without using state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to call a **snackbar component from material UI** inside a javascript that will alert me if it was successful or not inside this code

```
try {
  await message.save();
  setLoading(false);
} catch (error) {
  setLoading(false);
}
```

What do I do? I'm just new to react

Comment: Can you elaborate please? As of now i can't seem to figure out what exactly you want to do.

Comment: so, why is that not working as expected?